# Cin parameters to a custom class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have made a custom class, Person, which holds information about persons, from a job perspective.

```
class Person
{
    char* _name;
    char* _lName;
    char* _department;
    int _age, _salary;
public:
    Person(char* name, char* lName, char* department, int age, int salary);
    Person(void);
    ~Person(void);

    char* getFName(){return _name;};
    char* getLName(){return _lName;};
    char* getDepartment(){return _department;};
    int getSalary(){return _salary;};

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &cout, Person &person);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream& is, Person &person);
};
```

What I wish to accomplish, is to stream data into this class, using cin, in the form of a comma separated char*.

The cin overload:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Person &person)
{
    char* tmp="";
    is >> tmp;
    int i=0;
    int number=0;
    char** dataArray=new char*;
    dataArray[0]="";
    while(tmp[i]!= '\0')
    {
        if(tmp[i]==',')
        {
            number++;
            dataArray[number]="";
        }
        else
            dataArray+=tmp[i];
        i++;
    }
    person._name=dataArray[0];
    person._lName=dataArray[1];
    person._department=dataArray[2];
    person._salary=(int)dataArray[3];
    person._age=(int)dataArray[4];
    return is;
}
```

However, the program stops, with an error, at;

```
  is >> tmp;
```

I haven't manipulated istreams at all before, the error is probably due to faulty reasoning.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `tmp` is pointing to a string literal `""` which you cannot read data into. You would be *much* better off using `std::string` rather than `char*` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the size here:

```
char** dataArray=new char*;
```

I think you need:

```
char** dataArray=new char*[5];
```

You leak the memory for this variable. You seem to be manipulating the elements of this array as if they are `std::string`, but they are simple char arrays. You need to allocate and reallocate them. To avoid all that issues use `std::vector` and `std::string`. Your errors have nothing to do with `operator<<` itself.

Comment: I had no idea you could only stream into an std::string, thanks a bunch :)